# MySQL doesn't work through CodeIgniter, but works fine in vanilla PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So this is a pretty weird error.

This is how my `application/config/database.php` file is formatted:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'db_name';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;


/* End of file database.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/database.php */



$mysqli=mysqli_connect
(
  $db['default']['hostname'],
  $db['default']['username'],
  $db['default']['password'],
  $db['default']['database']
);
echo (mysqli_connect_errno()) ? "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error() : "Connected OK";
die( "\n<br>Filename: " .__FILE__ . "\n<br>Line number: " .__LINE__);
```

I get this error when I load the site:

```
Failed to connect to MySQL: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (13) 
Filename: /var/www/html/application/config/database.php 
Line number: 86
```

Now, here's the weird part. I made a new file in that folder, with the following code:

```
<?
define('BASEPATH', 'active');
require_once "database.php";
```

The response when I run `php test.php` from command line?

```
<pre>Array
(
    [hostname] => 127.0.0.1
    [username] => root
    [password] => 
    [database] => db_name
    [dbdriver] => mysql
    [dbprefix] =>
    [pconnect] =>
    [db_debug] =>
    [cache_on] =>
    [cachedir] =>
    [char_set] => utf8
    [dbcollat] => utf8_general_ci
    [swap_pre] =>
    [autoinit] => 1
    [stricton] =>
)
</pre>Connected OK
<br>Filename: /var/www/html/application/config/database.php
<br>Line number: 83
```

Why does `test.php` work from command line but trying the main site fail? Please help, I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Do NOT use `mysql_*` it has been removed and it will not work anymore, use `PDO` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or `mysqli` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: The mysql_* functions have died several years ago and no longer exist in PHP nowadays. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I've updated the script to use MySQLi drivers, but am still having the same issue :/

Comment: Why did you add `mysqli_connect()` to `database.php`?  It is likely the source of the error and is not needed.

Comment: To test the connection credentials directly. The idea is I made a new file outside the scope of CodeIgniter, and included only the database connection file, and it ran fine from command line. When I visit the website, I get a database connection error, suggesting something in CodeIgniter is modifying the connection handling.

Comment: What have you done to test the connection using CI? (without the direct call to `mysqli_connect()`)

Comment: @user2608562 Check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter database config file replace hostname

`$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';`

To

`$db['default']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';`

Note: when you use localhost to connect mysql tries to establish connection using sockets on Linux and pipes on Windows operating system.

IP address makes MySQL to establish connection using TCP/IP.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Arjun. I now get the following error: `Message: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (13)` But I can connect fine over MySQL console?

Comment: Can you use pdo instead of mysqli :) set dbdriver value to pdo.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help!

I figured it out. It was actually because selinux was disabling access to the database from Apache. I ran `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1` and it patched it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this in `database.php`. **Its Wrong**

```
$mysqli=mysqli_connect
(
  $db['default']['hostname'],
  $db['default']['username'],
  $db['default']['password'],
  $db['default']['database']
);
echo (mysqli_connect_errno()) ? "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error() : "Connected OK";
die( "\n<br>Filename: " .__FILE__ . "\n<br>Line number: " .__LINE__);
```

---

### Database config should be

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'db_name'; # Set Database name
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli'; # Changed
```

---

### How to load database??

In **apllication/config/autoload.php** add this

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

---

### How to check database is loaded?

**If there is an  error** below image(image 01) will show up. **If there is no error it will load your site as usual**.

**Image 01**
[image]